# Error in R and H2O initialize - Java path not found

Tags: java, r, h2o

I installed version `3.2.0.4` of `h2o` on `R 4.0.3`, when I start `h2o` I get the error message:

```
simpleError in system2 (command, "-version", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE): '"C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jre1.8.0_261 \ bin \ java.exe "'not found>
Error in value [[3L]] (cond):
   You have a 32-bit version of Java. H2O works best with 64-bit Java.
Please download the latest Java SE JDK from the following URL:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath (path.expand (path), winslash, mustWork):
   path [1] = "C: \ Program Files \ Java \ jre1.8.0_261 / bin / java.exe": The system cannot find the path specified
```

It turns out that the version of java installed is 64 bits. There is no other version 32 installed.

System = Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

64bit JDK is required. See the [requirements](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/welcome.html#requirements).

Comment: For whatever reason, H2O is finding the incorrect Java (the one you don't want). H2O will check your "PATH" environment variable then if no Java is found, it will check "JAVA_HOME". Check that your "PATH" has your desired Java directory listed first. Also, check if you have a directory set for "JAVA_HOME".